# Override equals

Tags: java, arraylist

I have this class:

```
public class Phone{ 
    private String number;
    //get and set of class
}
```

Then i have another class that uses the "Phone"

```
public class Antena{
   private String name;
   private ArrayList<Phone> phones;
}
```

Now before add an element i would like only add if the element don't exist in the array. I'm new in Java and after some research i have found that i need to override the equals method. So can anyone give me some hints please?

This is how i use the equals method:

```
if(!phones.equals(phone))
   phones.add(phone);
```

Comment: Consider using a Set then. It won't allow duplicates.

Comment: Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html for how to override methods - if you have more questions, please ask something specific, including information about how far you've got and where you're stuck.

Comment: I know how to override methods. I have created the override function in the class Antena and on Phone but didn't work.

Comment: You need to override both equals() and hashCode().  See a [sample here.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java

Comment: Show the code that "didn't work".

Comment: And explain *how* it didn't work: example inputs, expected output, actual output.

Comment: Do not overconstrue: a simple `Set<String> phones = new TreeSet<>();` will do nicely. Elsewhere use your IDE to override methods like equals/hashcode.

Comment: public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        Phone t = (Phone ) obj;
        return t.number== this.number;
    }

Comment: Instead of ArrayList use sets. It won't add duplicate elements.

Comment: @user2295277 dont post code in comment but include it in your question using [[edit]] option.

Comment: Strings use equals() for comparison, not ==

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments now have enough information to actually answer the question.

**Part 1**

Implement equals:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) { 
  if (obj == null) return false;
  if (obj.getClass() != this.getClass()) return false;
  Phone t = (Phone ) obj; 
  return t.number.equals(this.number);
}
```

**Part 2**

Implement hash code

```
public int hashCode() {
  return number.hashCode();
}
```

**Part 3**

Use a set instead of an ArrayList to require uniqueness..

```
private HashSet<Phone> phones;
```

Comment: `hashCode()` returns an `int`, not a `long`.

Comment: And equals() should not throw a ClassCastException if the argument is not a Phone.

Comment: Actually you should check: if (obj instanceof Phone) or you will receive an exception if you for instance have a String as Object

Comment: Oops.  Fixed.  As you can see, I usually use my IDE to generate this method!

Comment: Re equals - I was trying to show it the way the original poster did.  Split them into two examples to make this clearer.

Comment: Yes, but it's not just that one is better than the other. It's that one is correct and the other is not.

Comment: I don't disagree.  I guess I was trying to highlight == vs equals poorly.  I'll remove it since it isn't making the point I was trying to make.

Comment: I can't use an Set because the Teacher want us to use an ArrayList. I have tried your code and it still adds the phone if already exists another with the same number!

Comment: @user2295277: You don't have to do anything with a Set to prevent duplicates. With a List, you have to do it by yourself: `if (!list.contains(phone)) { list.add(phone);}`. You should learn to read the javadoc: it shows all the available methods and explain what they do and how they work.

Answer (score 0):

You override equals method to do equality test of the class objects.
For example you have two Phone objects p1 and p2.

```
Phone p1 = new Phone();
Phone p2 = new Phone();
p1.setNumber(10);
p2.setNumber(10);
\\Ideally these two objects are equal but when you try to do equality test , it will return false.
System.out.println(p1==p2);  // outputs false because p1 and p2 are two different references
```

holding different memory addresses.
Also ,

```
System.out.println(p1.equals(p2));  // prints false when not overrided
```

When you override equals method you can add a criteria to logically test these two objects.

```
public boolean equals(Object obj)
  {

    if (!(obj instanceof Phone)) 
      return false;
    return this.getNumber() == ((Phone)obj).getNumber();
  }
```

Now if you call equals method on p1 and p2 objects , it will return true.
Equals method test is useful when you want to equate two class objects on basis of instance variables and not reference addresses.

Comment: I have done that but it still don't work! I have added more info to main post.

Comment: the way you implemented equals is not the correst way. use the way i override equals